# Close UserControl in Form Panel from button in this UserControl in C#

Tags: c#, button, user-controls, panel, backcolor

In my project, there is a Form and some UserControls, and in the Form is a ToolStrip with some buttons and one Panel, and in the UserControls is a button to close it.
When click on each button in the ToolStrip, the backColor for this button changes, and open one UserControl in the Panel.
Now I have two questions:

1. How to close UserControl from the button in it? I do not want to hide it, but close it.
2. When UserControl is closed, how to change the backColor for the ToolStrip button to the default color again?

I tried this in Form and work fine:

```
UserControl1 uc1;

private void toolStripBtn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
pnl.Controls.Add(uc1);
uc1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
uc1.BringToFront();
uc1.Show();
        // To change all button backColor in ToolStrip to default except Btn1
foreach (ToolStripItem btn in toolStrip.Items)
            {
                if (btn is ToolStripButton)
                {
                    btn.BackColor = Color.White;
                }
            }
            toolStripBtn1.BackColor = Color.Green;
        }
```

What is the code in UserControl to close it and change backColor for ToolStrip Btn1 to default again.

Comment: See my answer at following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net.  The form has e.Cancel = true; which keep the form open after returning.  You can use create a method called default and set buttons back to default.  Or you can use "uc1 = new UserControl1()" Or uc1.Close()

Comment: Thank you for reply, here I talk about button in UserControl in Panel in Form (to close this UserControl) and the backColor for another button in ToolStrip in Form. not open form in form.

Comment: You need to add another button in the form to close and a Click method to work with the button.  Instead of hiding the form in the new method close the form.

Comment: I do not need to close the form, I need to close UserControl which in panel in form, and button close in this UserControl not in the form.